# Python - tokenizing, replacing words

Tags: python, dictionary, tokenize, string-parsing

I'm trying to create something like sentences with random words put into them. To be specific, I'd have something like:

```
"The weather today is [weather_state]."
```

and to be able to do something like finding all tokens in [brackets] and than exchange them for a randomized counterpart from a dictionary or a list, leaving me with:

```
"The weather today is warm."
"The weather today is bad."
```

or

```
"The weather today is mildly suiting for my old bones."
```

Keep in mind, that the position of the [bracket] token wouldn't be always in the same position and there would be multiple bracketed tokens in my string, like:

```
"[person] is feeling really [how] today, so he's not going [where]."
```

I really don't know where to start with this or is this even the best solution to use tokenize or token modules with this. Any hints that would point me in the right direction greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Just for clarification, I don't really need to use square brackets, any non-standard character will do.

Comment: Might be a stupid suggestion, but have you looked at string formatting with `{}`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for re.sub with a callback function:

```
words = {
    'person': ['you', 'me'],
    'how': ['fine', 'stupid'],
    'where': ['away', 'out']
}

import re, random

def random_str(m):
    return random.choice(words[m.group(1)])


text = "[person] is feeling really [how] today, so he's not going [where]."
print re.sub(r'\[(.+?)\]', random_str, text)

#me is feeling really stupid today, so he's not going away.
```

Note that unlike the `format` method, this allows for more sophisticated processing of placeholders, e.g.

```
[person:upper] got $[amount if amount else 0] etc
```

Basically, you can build your own "templating engine" on top of that.

Comment: That's great, I like how I how it's clean and efficient. It does it job and being a Python beginner understanding it gives me an advantage. :) The smart thing would be to write a dictionary file, save it on disc and load it into the "words" dictionary here... Any pointers on how a dictionary file syntax would look like in a file? Many thanks!

Comment: @bitworks: the simplest and most convenient option is json: http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `format` method.

```
>>> a = 'The weather today is {weather_state}.'
>>> a.format(weather_state = 'awesome')
'The weather today is awesome.'
>>>
```

Also:

```
>>> b = '{person} is feeling really {how} today, so he\'s not going {where}.'
>>> b.format(person = 'Alegen', how = 'wacky', where = 'to work')
"Alegen is feeling really wacky today, so he's not going to work."
>>>
```

Of course, this method only works **IF** you can switch from square brackets to curly ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you use braces instead of brackets, then your string could be used as a [string formatting template](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). You could fill it in with lots of substitutions using [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools as IT

text = "{person} is feeling really {how} today, so he's not going {where}."
persons = ['Buster', 'Arthur']
hows = ['hungry', 'sleepy']
wheres = ['camping', 'biking']

for person, how, where in IT.product(persons, hows, wheres):
    print(text.format(person=person, how=how, where=where))
```

yields

```
Buster is feeling really hungry today, so he's not going camping.
Buster is feeling really hungry today, so he's not going biking.
Buster is feeling really sleepy today, so he's not going camping.
Buster is feeling really sleepy today, so he's not going biking.
Arthur is feeling really hungry today, so he's not going camping.
Arthur is feeling really hungry today, so he's not going biking.
Arthur is feeling really sleepy today, so he's not going camping.
Arthur is feeling really sleepy today, so he's not going biking.
```

---

To generate random sentences, you could use [random.choice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
for i in range(5):
    person = random.choice(persons)
    how = random.choice(hows)
    where = random.choice(wheres)
    print(text.format(person=person, how=how, where=where))
```

---

If you must use brackets **and** have no braces in your format, you 
could replace the brackets with braces and then proceed as above:

```
text = "[person] is feeling really [how] today, so he's not going [where]."
text = text.replace('[','{').replace(']','}')
```

Comment: This `person=person, how=how, where=where` thing can get really stupid if they have hundreds of them.

Comment: I decided to stay away from `format(**locals())` here because it would not make it clear exactly how the substitution was being made. But if you did have hundreds of variables, `format(**locals())` would be the way to go.